# How to view an image in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [See images in SSMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669952/see-images-in-ssms)

Is there any way to view images stored in the sql server database table. Of course we can view this from the application(.net, java), but i want this from sql server managements studio. Is there any setting or any. Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: you can do this with an add-in (ssmsboost): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669952/see-images-in-ssms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server Management Studio supports only the import and export of image and it doesn't support viewing and editing feature of  lob (image) data type.

`SqlLobEditor` will support the those feature's [refer](http://www.withdata.com/sqllobeditor.html)